# I cant see request from SQL in web browser

Tags: php, sql-server

We have a strange issue. When I launch `php -q myscript.php`  I can see result from sql.

If try to execute this in a web browser:

```
http://201.220.222.xxx/myscript.php
```

It only returns:

`Warning: mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server: 192.168.x.x`  etc..

Why does this only work on console?

Comment: probably selinux thing. type this in command line and see if it fixes it "setenforce 0"

Comment: You're trying to connect to a local address from your web-server.  When you ran this script, was it running on the web server, or your own machine?  The `192.168.` address must be a local address known by your web server.

Comment: Thanks, where add these line??, In fact all is running local, the server linux and SQL.